# Where can i find collection of Problems on Transformations of random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, random-functions

I am looking for a book or a website or any other source where i could practice questions on finding PDF of $Y=g(X)$ where the PDF of the random variable $X$ is given. Any inputs for this ?